# Adobe Illustrator: How to fill in colors between lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

I am making a 3D letter and I want to fill in some parts to give it a 3D look. So far I have used black lines to make it but I want to fill in-between the lines.

Can someone show me what to do?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question with what you've done and what you tried? Right now I'm not even sure what program you're using since the title says Illustrator but you tagged it Photoshop. Update the question using the [edit] though not comments please.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25882/technique-for-filling-color-to-grouped-objects Or http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25167/how-can-i-easily-add-color-to-unclosed-shapes or http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29029/how-to-fill-in-areas-surrounded-by-line-segments?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that you're not using the pen or shape tools. In this case you'll want to use the live paint tool. Select your design and press the <kbd>K</kbd> key on the keyboard to activate the **Live Paint Bucket Tool**. Then choose a color and start filling.

In the future you may want to use the pen tool. This will give you more control.

[image: Live Pain]

Comment: It says I can't for some reason

Comment: @user114908 you have to select everything first before you click the bucket icon